# Problem with postgres \copy command for export query resullt to file

Tags: postgresql

I tried to export a select query result to a csv file. I used Postgres \copy metacommand and command line (psql) to do it. But I got a Syntax error and can't understand why. The Query looks fine to me. Maybe the reason for using metacommand instead of COPY?
The query

```
\copy
  (
    SELECT geo_name, state_us_abbreviation, housing_unit_count_100_percent
    FROM us_counties_2010
    ORDER BY housing_unit_count_100_percent DESC
    LIMIT 20
  )
TO '/username/Desktop/us_counties_2010_export.csv' 
WITH(FORMAT CSV, HEADER, DELIMITER '|');
```

Error message

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TO"
LINE 7: TO '/username/Desktop/us_counties_2010_export.csv'
```

Comment: To rule out the obvious: you **are** using `psql` to run this?

Comment: using `psql` run `psql -d yourdb -c "COPY .... TO STDOUT " > /username/Desktop/us_counties_2010_export.csv`

Comment: Please show the error message.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes psql

Comment: Laurenz Albe  - Error message added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\copy` is a metacommand given to `psql`, not a regular command sent to the server.  So like other metacommands, the entire `\copy` command must all be given on one line and doesn't end in a `;` but rather a newline.

If you look closely, you will see the first error you got was `\copy: arguments required`

Comment: worked in one line and without ; Thanks a lot!